# Wayland replacement for dmenu

Tags: wayland, menu

In X11 I like to use dmenu to select from a list of items (common commands, URL bookmarks, etc.) and paste them into whatever program I have in front of me. Due to various issues, I'm going to have to start migrating away from X11 and towards Wayland.

I've looked at [fuzzel](https://codeberg.org/dnkl/fuzzel) as a dmenu replacement but I don't want to go through the trouble of installing a new window manager like sway or wlroot, that seems like a headache and learning curve I wish to avoid. Is there a dmenu replacement that will work with the default Ubuntu Wayland session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My replacement is fuzzy finder (`sudo apt install fzf`), running in a terminal emulator, which I use on the Gnome Desktop.

Create a script, e.g with the name `fzfmenu` with the following content:

```
#!/bin/sh
gnome-terminal -- sh -c "fzf  < /proc/$$/fd/0 > /proc/$$/fd/1"
```

Use it like:

```
echo -e "yes\nno" | fzfmenu
```

For this purpose, I actually use the terminal emulator `foot`, a fast Wayland terminal emulator. It looks good for a menu and loads very fast.

[Credit where credit is due](https://www.reddit.com/r/commandline/comments/jatyek/using_fzf_as_a_dmenurofi_replacement/)

Comment: And how would I bind it to a keyboard shortcut? In Ubuntu GNOME I went to keyboard settings and added this as the command: `gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c "cat ~/my-items.txt | fzfmenu.sh"'` as a test. It works as you describe, it just doesn't print whatever I select to the application I had in focus before initiating the keyboard shortcut.

Comment: That is a totally different question with a different answer. You would face the same problem with `dmenu` or `rofi`. Answer: either make a script and call that, or wrap the commands in `sh -c '...'`. A question from my part to you: how did you "paste" using dmenu?